# Progressbar that has more than 100 files to Upload

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, progress

i am currently developing a Progress bar (Using Winforms) that would be Shown while E-Mails are Uploaded.
now the Problem I'm having is that if i Upload more than 100 E-mails, the Progress bar won't load.

here is the method which is used to set the amount for which the Progress bar is filled for each E-Mail (if there is 2 E-mails give me 2 times 50 %, if there is 4 do it in 25% Steps .........):

```
        public StatusUpload(int uploadAmount)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        progressBar1.Step = 100 / uploadAmount;
    }
```

Does anybody know how i could solve this Problem?
Thanks a lot in Advance, your help is Appreciated

Answer (score 7):

Just set the `Maximum` property of the progress bar to the number of emails and increment the value by each email as it's sent.  Given that, there would need to be no additional calculations. e.g.

```
progressBar1.Maximum = numberOfEmails;
foreach(var email in emails)
{
  // Send Email
  progressBar1.Value++;
}
```